# Copy all "xxx.dll" files but not "xxxd.dll" ones

Tags: regex, qt, powershell, dll, copy

In order to deploy an application I must to copy Qt libraries into a folder.
In the `bin` folder of Qt installation there are two version of a library:

- Qt5xxx.dll (release)
- Qt5xxxd.dll (debug)

Is there a way to copy all release libraries, discarding the debug ones, that have a `d` at the end of the file name? I'd like to avoid to create an explicit array with filenames because they are a lot, and because I want to generalize this to other libraries that have the same naming convention.

Comment: Is the number of variables (`x`'s) always the same?

Comment: yes. I've `Qt5Core.dll` and `Qt5Cored.dll`, `Qt5Widgets.dll` and `Qt5Widgetsd.dll` and so on. Every library follows same debug/release convention. I don't change their number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply grab all files in the `bin` directory and then filter away those where the base name ends in `d`:

```
$ReleaseFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\qt\project\bin\ -Filter Qt5*.dll |Where-Object BaseName -notlike *d
```

Grab the `Name` property of each item if you want an array of (Release) names:

```
$ReleaseFiles |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thanks! Then I copy them with `$ReleaseFiles | Copy-Item -Path {Join-Path $qtFolder $_} -Dest $destinationFolder`

Comment: This won't work when the basename already ends in a d, e.g. Qt5fred.dll vs Qt5fredd.dll